# How do I mention groups in the body of an email sent to slack channel?

Tags: slack, slack-api

I'm trying to tag a group in the body of an email sent to a Slack channel email address (sent using an external API). I looked around and apparently, it cannot be done unless it's a Slack message (and not an email).
Just wanted to check here before I look for alternative solutions.

tried this already, and the text just shows up without any formatting.
https://api.slack.com/reference/surfaces/formatting#mentioning-groups